# Calculate confidence interval

Tags: statistics

> The distribution of days that are required to complete a certain
>   activity can be approximated by a standard normal distribution with a
>   mean of 500 days and a standard deviation of 12 days. What is the
>   approximate 95% confidence interval in days for the activity ?

I have read this [example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval#Practical_example), but found it hard to understand. I hope maybe someone can give me a clearer explanation. I have to admit, I'm not very good with Math!

Comment: I found it hard to understand. How could I try anything without understanding it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea for any "Gaussian based" (read: pretty much all of them in a basic stats class) is that you do $\hat{x} \pm \mbox{critical value} \times sd$.

Here, $\hat{x}$ is your estimate, $sd$ is your standard deviation of the estimate and the ``critical value" is what you look up from a distribution.

You know that you want a 95% confidence interval. Using a normal distribution, you know that if $z = 1.96$ you have 2.5% of the area to the right of that and 2.5% of the area to the left of $-z$. Since that equals 5% total, that's your "critical value".

The rest is just plug and play.

Your estimate of the time of the activity is 500. Your standard deviation is 12 days.

Slight addendum: When I said $sd$ is the standard deviation, I meant the standard deviation of your *estimate*. Sometimes, you want a confidence interval for the mean, $\bar{x}$. In that case, the $sd(\bar{x}) = sd(x)/\sqrt{n}$. In your case, they just give you the final standard deviation so it's easy to use.

Thus the confidence interval is:

$(500 - 1.96 *12, 500 + 1.96*12)$ = (476.48, 523.52).

Notice that the confidence interval is symmetric around 500.

Comment: Very clear explanation! Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

The relevant section in the Wikipedia article is $$\left[\bar X - 1.96 \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}, \bar X + 1.96 \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}\right].$$  However, in your case, you aren't given a sample from which to estimate the population mean and standard error:  instead, you are directly given $\mu$ and $\sigma$, so your confidence interval is simpler:  $$\left[\mu - 1.96 \sigma, \mu + 1.96 \sigma\right],$$ where $\mu = 500$ and $\sigma = 12$.